# Вывести random без повторений

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите сделать random без повторений

```
   for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {

            var text = new String('');

            for (var c = 0; c < 5; c++) {
                let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * response.items[i].listTagDto.length)
                text = text + "<a href=\"#\" class=\"tag\"> " + response.items[i].listTagDto[random].name + " </a>"
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var shuffledNames = response.items[i].listTagDto.map(i => i.name).sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
var text = shuffledNames.map(i => `<a href="#" class="tag"> ${i} </a>`).join('');
```

Comment: Спасибо,большое)